# How to get Heart Pendant and Purple Fin

Tags: candy-box-2

I've done everything but kill the developer and am missing the Heart Pendant.  I've spent a couple hours AFKing the ocean and no fin.  I have no clue where the Heart Pendant is and can't find an answer anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

The Heart Pendant is located:

> In the hole, the first chest on the left

The Purple Fin is found by

> Killing the shark with a purple fin after a long time under the sea.

Comment: I've spent multiple hours afk in the ocean killing sharks and still no purple fin.

Comment: Really? I found it in like 10 minutes. Keep trying.